# Kubernetes cannot be handled as a Secret illegal base64 data when using environment variable

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to apply kubernetes code that was given for me. I am getting an error:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "infra/ecr-creds/rendered.yml": Secret in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: illegal base64 data at input byte 0
```

From what I understand, the error is coming from this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: aws-ecr-creds-secret
  namespace: whatever
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: aws-multi-ecr-credentials
    helm.sh/chart: aws-multi-ecr-credentials-1.4.3
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: aws-ecr-creds-novisign
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.4.3"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
type: Opaque
data:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
```

I tried to set the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` variable using:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo "...code..." | base64)
```

but it doesn't work. What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: If you're creating that yaml in helm, you'll want to either use its [built-in support for base64](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#encoding-functions) or instead of `data:` which presumes you have already encoded the string, you can use [the `stringData:` flavor](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#restriction-names-data) and k8s will encode it for you on the way into the API. Also, w.r.t. your "echo|base64" that's a common bug -- the `echo` will have a trailing newline, which base64 will encode; you'll want `echo -n` or `printf`

Answer (score 5):

You should use `stringData`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: aws-ecr-creds-secret
  namespace: whatever
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: aws-multi-ecr-credentials
    helm.sh/chart: aws-multi-ecr-credentials-1.4.3
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: aws-ecr-creds-novisign
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.4.3"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
type: Opaque
stringData:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
```

Link references:
https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/cuongquocvn/aws-cli-kubectl